# decipher the SAML response from ping identity to python flask application using AES_256 algorithm

Tags: python, flask, ping

How to set up a python web application to receive SAML response and how can I decipher the SAML assertion.
I have a FLask application and I was able to get the SAML response but stuck with the decipher part

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the parsing and deciphering by yourself, use appropriate packages, for example [python3-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml).